# JSC: FATAL: Attempting to release access but the mutator does not have access

Tags: ios, xcode, destructor, javascriptcore

We are using JavaScriptCore in our iOS application. When deinitializing the module we get this crash

```
FATAL: Attempting to release access but the mutator does not have access.
Exception: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1bacbb6fc)
```

This is the call stack

[image: call stack]

**Any tips on what the reason could be?**